# Clearing RAM stop showing Notifications

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, background-process

Using `AlarmManager` class i am able to schedule notification after 200 msec(For testing) code:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
int interval =200;
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),interval, pendingIntent);
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
   SetUpNotification.createNotification();

}}
```

But when I am Clearing RAM these notifications Stops and even if I close activity I can get these notifications, but not after clearing ram, I don't know what mistake am doing please help

Comment: is this happening in all phones ?

Comment: @Saveen Only checked in one phone, is that possible that i can vary?

Comment: yes i have got issue in mi phones that have problem and one more phone Lenovo a1000 that have also same problem

Comment: mi phones have there own customize os, so if you clear RAM it automatically disconnect all services and alarm manager

Comment: yes i have MI phone

Comment: yes you need manually start service from settings

Comment: So no code change required? or should i go for [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123089/discussion-between-saveen-and-phpdroid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution for MIUI** 7.0 => Security => Autostart => select Apps that you want to run in background => Reboot After reboot your device should able to run your application services in background like other android devices do.

[MIUI 4.0 settings](http://en.miui.com/thread-33826-1-1.html)

[MIUI AutoStart Detailed Description](http://en.miui.com/thread-117992-1-1.html)